# RestKit & AFNetworking store header on all responses

Tags: ios, rest, http-headers, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

The API I am using requires me to send a signature string in the header of all my requests, in order to identify my session.

I get this signature from a header I read in the API's responses. The first call I make doesn't need the signature, but all subsequent requests do. The signature can change at any time, so I need to update my default header if I'm sent a new signature string.

Some of the calls I make use [RKObjectManager sharedManager], in some others I use AFNetworking directly using [RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient

What I would like to do is find a way to configure my underlying AFNetworking client so for every response that comes in I read the signature from the header and update my default header accordingly.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You mean something automatic, without you having to process the returned headers yourself? Or by subs classing something to insert this logic? Did you have any ideas / try anything?

Comment: I did a similar thing in AFNetworking to send a default header in my requests, which I accomplished by subclassing the request serialiser. I imagined the same thing would be possible in RestKit , although it doesn't seem to have AFNetworking's response serialiser class in it to subclass.